# Entity Framework 4.3.1 always run all migrations on Update-Database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4, devart, entity-framework-migrations

I have created an initial migration with `Add-Migration`. When I run `Update-Database` on an empty DB it creates all tables, including adding an entry in the __MigrationHistory table.

Now I run `Update-Database` again just to test, and instead of "No changes detected" I get this:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -Project testProject.Web
Using StartUp project 'testProject.Web'.
Target database is: 'testProject_dbo' (DataSource: localhost, Provider: Devart.Data.MySql, Origin: Explicit).
Applying explicit migrations: [201203151243164_Start].
Applying explicit migration: 201203151243164_Start.
CREATE TABLE attachments ( 
 ...table data...
)
Table 'attachments' already exists
Table 'attachments' already exists
```

It seems like the update is unaware of the current DB state. The only solution is to delete all tables and update. That works also if I add more migrations.

As you see, I am using a different database provider than usual (Devart.Data.Mysql), but I'm not sure if the problem is there. Maybe I'm missing something trivial?

Comment: Can you validate if this also happens on SQL Server with default provider?

Comment: Yes it works with the default provider, connecting to .\SQLEXPRESS: It creates the database and when I run it again: No pending explicit migrations.

Comment: In such case you should contact Devart support for further investigation.

Comment: I did that, just wanted to make sure this wasn't expected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved after communicating with [DevArt](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=23654). I never called the `IgnoreSchemaName` workaround in the Configuration class that was generated when running `Enable-Migrations`. To summarize, this is the class that made it work finally:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        // Because the Package Manager Console (NuGet) instantiates YourDbContext with the empty constructor,
        // a custom connection must be specified. Based on http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/?p=5603
        // Note that the MySqlProviderFactory must also be present in Web.config or App.config in the *startup project*
        // for this to work! Configuration example:

        /*
          <system.data>
            <DbProviderFactories>
              <clear />
              <remove invariant="Devart.Data.MySql" />
              <add name="dotConnect for MySQL" invariant="Devart.Data.MySql" description="Devart dotConnect for MySQL" type="Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.MySql, Version=6.30.196.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
            </DbProviderFactories>
          </system.data>
        */

        // Apply the IgnoreSchemaName workaround
        MySqlEntityProviderConfig.Instance.Workarounds.IgnoreSchemaName = true;

        // Create a custom connection to specify the database and set a SQL generator for MySql.
        var connectionInfo = MySqlConnectionInfo.CreateConnection("<Your ConnectionString>");

        TargetDatabase = connectionInfo;
        SetSqlGenerator(connectionInfo.GetInvariantName(), new MySqlEntityMigrationSqlGenerator());

        // Enable automatic migrations if you like
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

        // There is some problem with referencing EntityFramework 4.3.1.0 for me, so another fix that needs
        // to be applied in Web.config is this:

        /*
          <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding>
              <!-- This redirection is needed for EntityFramework Migrations through the Package Manager Console (NuGet) -->
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
          </runtime>
        */

        // After these Web.config additions, running migrations in Package Manager Console should be as easy as:
        // Update-Database -Verbose -ProjectName Your.MigrationsProject

        // Creating new migrations:
        // Add-Migration -Name MigrationDescription -ProjectName Your.MigrationsProject
    }
}
```

After that I emptied the database one more time to generate a correct migration history entry, and everything was fine. [DevArt](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=23654) gives more details about the configuration.

Comment: Ah thanks for this! It was very helpful to me. Fyi, you're missing the beginning assemblyBinding tag in your commented out web.config fragment.

Comment: Oh, where did that one go? Well, fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same odd behaviour, but in my case it turned out to be much simpler: a code merge had reset my Startup Project to the default, which was not the project that contained the migrations.

I didn't notice until I tried the `-Verbose` flag, which explicitly laid out that my Startup project was not the same as the NuGet project configured in Package Manager.

Worth the sanity check!

Comment: Solved it for me. I thought the 'Default Project' in the package manager window was the default project used, apparently not!